# create new view controller as .swift instead of .h

Tags: swift, xcode

Whenever I try to add a new view controller it automatically creates a .h file.  I want a .swift file, but I can not find any information online.  Every site assumes I know how to do this.  Please advise!

Comment: Maybe you are programming in Objective C instead of Swift!

Comment: My default view controller (the one my app started out with) is in swift, so I'm assuming I'm working in swift.  If not, how can I change this?

Comment: When you create the new file, click the Language dropdown in the dialog and select Swift instead of Objective-C.

Comment: so I have to start my project over from scratch?  I am dragging 'view controller' from the menu in the bottom right to add to the storyboard.  is there a way I can just add a new view controller like this and have it create a swift file instead of a .h file?

Comment: @chodobaggins: Please pardon my ignorance: Dragging a view controller to the storyboard does not create a source file, or does it?

Comment: @MartinR - it certainly seems to - the Assistant Editor, which I always use, shows a .h file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this how you create a new view controller? 
[image: Picure]

Comment: This is what I've had to do, and manually reassign the file to the ViewController on my storyboard through the properties menu on the right of the screen.